# How to run an ssl EJB Webservice?

Tags: web-services, security, jakarta-ee, glassfish, jax-ws

I have created an Ejb endpoint WebService (.EAR) using metro and glassfish 3.1.2(b5) .
The wsdl file is published and accessible via https .
I generated the client artifact from the secured url and when I Run the client I get this error (server side):

```
ATTENTION: Invalid request scheme for Endpoint my_web_service. Expected https . Received http
```

This how I configured the secure connexion:

```
<glassfish-ejb-jar>
    <enterprise-beans>


        <ejb>
            <ejb-name>my_web_service</ejb-name>
            <webservice-endpoint>
                <port-component-name>my_web_service</port-component-name>
                <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
            </webservice-endpoint>
        </ejb>  

    </enterprise-beans>
</glassfish-ejb-jar>
```

If I change  the implementation to a servlet endpoint (.war) everything run ok so I think that I'm missing something in the configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make this work you need to update the bundled version of grizzly in glassfish to 1.9.55 .

Comment: Hey mate,
I have a similar problem and I couldn't try your solution completely.
how did you update grizzly in glassfish. In mq/lib/ there is a grizzly.jar, and there are of course lots of other grizzly libraries all around.
glassfish 3.1.2.2 still has the good old 1.9.36. I tried to include the one you mentioned for grizzly-nio-network and its dependencies (I couldn't find the one with only grizzly.jar) to no avail.
my question: how to update grizzly in glassfish